# Flask / uWSGI / CentOS - updates do not work

Tags: python, nginx, centos, uwsgi, wsgi

to be honest i am a Noob if it comes to servers & maintenance.

I followed exactly the following guide to create my first "Hello There" page which worked out so far.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7

But after trying to update my homepage by inserting more code into my Application and saving the script the server output in my Browser still remains the same old "hello there".

I am better with functional programming (mathematics) and database handling, but since I have to supply my team colleagues with some tools i thought about a quick homepage. Unfortunatley it is harder than expected to set up a python hp.

Thank you in advanced 
Stefan

EDIT:
I really followed the link above 1 to 1. Ht here are my codes:

**TAOWeb.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():
return "<h style='color:green'> HELLO ASDF! </h1>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**TAOWeb.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 5

socket = TAOWeb.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from TAOWeb import application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

and the `/etc/systemd/system/TAOWeb.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve TAOWeb
After=network.target

[Service]
User=tao
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/tao/TAOWeb
Environment="PATH=/home/tao/TAOWeb/env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/tao/TAOWeb/env/bin/uwsgi --ini TAOWeb.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Last but not least the nginx Config:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 185.164.5.211;

location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/tao/TAOWeb/TAOWeb.sock;
    }

}

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
   }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

It is the standard config with only included the 1st Server part.

Does this help?

Best
Stefan

Comment: There is no way for us to help you without your code.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `--py-autoreload=1` option when you run the uWSGI server, e.g. `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http -w wsgi --py-autoreload=1`

Comment: Did you reload Flask before visiting the page again? If so, perhaps your browser is caching the page. Try using Ctrl-R to reload or open a "private window" to make sure no cached version of your page is loaded.

Comment: You have a typo in `<h`, should be `<h1`. BTW, you have two server directives defined, both for listening to port 80. You should delete the second one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your code is right and are using Google chrome try clearing your cache

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try to use a new browser and it will make the trick for you.
Me - I had problem it Chrome, it worked after clear the cache, but the same doesn't happen with FireFox, over FireFox works like a charm.
You can try others browsers as well just in case.